# (fixed) I can't reboot iphone due to modal update notification

Tags: iphone, software-update, restart

fixed with this support link : https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201412

---

Kind of a *weird* annoying problem.

I just updated to ios 17.

Update completed normally, I went in and there's a modal prompt with an OK button on top of everything.

I cannot accept the (in french) "Mise à jour logicielle" prompt.

I cannot swipe to unlock the phone.

I cannot use the side buttons as instructed by : https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/iph8903c3ee6/17.0/ios/17.0

The reboot/restart slider is behind the modal prompt; I can "click" the OK button, but nothing happens.

Nothing happens when I connect to my Mac or my PC with iTunes open.

I tried the ReiBoot app on my mac and I cant even reset my phone (because I can't shut down the phone).

Any suggestions before I go down to the apple store ?

Comment: Did you also check the 'frozen' link from there? https://support.apple.com/HT201412

Comment: ohhhh I missed that one.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad it worked, but please don't put fixed or solved in the title or question body - that's a reddit thing. SE prefers an actual answer below the question, hopefully marked as accepted [which may make you wait a day or two for your own answer] & better as an explanation rather than just a link :)